# Kubernetes: Why does patching a custom resource's /status subresource update the parent resource?

Tags: kubernetes, patch, watch, status, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm trying to understand Kubernetes behaviour as it pertains to custom resources and their subresources -- specifically the `status` subresource.

**Specifically, I want to update the `status` subresource without modifying the parent custom resource.**

To the best of my understanding, this *should* be possible. I've reviewed the documentation [here][1], but I cannot seem to get it to work as anticipated.

I am testing using Docker Desktop's **Kubernetes `1.19.3`**.

Here is the scenario ...

1. Create this simple CRD:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: greetings.k8s.test.io
spec:
  group: k8s.test.io
  versions:
    - name: v1alpha1
      served: true
      storage: true
      schema:
        openAPIV3Schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              description: Greeting is the Schema for the Greetings Operator
              type: object
              properties:
                message:
                  description: A friendly greeting
                  type: string
                  default: Hello World!
            status:
              type: object
              properties:
                ready:
                  description: The resource's readiness
                  type: boolean
      additionalPrinterColumns:
      - name: ready
        type: boolean
        description: Readiness of the created resource
        jsonPath: .status.ready
      subresources:
        status: {}
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: greetings
    singular: greeting
    kind: Greeting
    shortNames:
    - grt
```

2. Create a demo resource:

```
apiVersion: k8s.test.io/v1alpha1
kind: Greeting
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  message: Hi there!
```

3. Fire up a proxy:

```
kubectl proxy &
```

4. Establish a watch on custom resource:

```
curl -L -s -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json, */*" \
127.0.0.1:8001/apis//k8s.test.io/v1alpha1/watch/namespaces/default/greetings
```

At this point, you should see output similar the following:

```
{"type":"ADDED","object":{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Greeting","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1\",\"kind\":\"Greeting\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"demo\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"message\":\"Hi there!\"}}\n"},"creationTimestamp":"2020-12-10T04:02:55Z","generation":1,"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{".":{},"f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":{}}},"f:spec":{".":{},"f:message":{}}},"manager":"kubectl-client-side-apply","operation":"Update","time":"2020-12-10T04:02:55Z"}],"name":"demo","namespace":"default","resourceVersion":"532930","selfLink":"/apis/k8s.test.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/greetings/demo","uid":"40f3a618-74e5-4b14-9bd4-2eb47366d804"},"spec":{"message":"Hi there!"}}}
```

5. `PATCH` the `/status` subresource

```
curl -k -s -X PATCH -H "Accept: application/json, */*" \
-H "Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json" \
127.0.0.1:8001/apis/k8s.test.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/greetings/demo/status \
--data '{"status":{"ready":true}}'
```

Confusingly, after submitting the `PATCH` our watch on the parent resource produces ...

```
{"type":"MODIFIED","object":{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Greeting","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1\",\"kind\":\"Greeting\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"demo\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"message\":\"Hi there!\"}}\n"},"creationTimestamp":"2020-12-10T04:02:55Z","generation":1,"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{".":{},"f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":{}}},"f:spec":{".":{},"f:message":{}}},"manager":"kubectl-client-side-apply","operation":"Update","time":"2020-12-10T04:02:55Z"},{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:status":{".":{},"f:ready":{}}},"manager":"curl","operation":"Update","time":"2020-12-10T04:05:22Z"}],"name":"demo","namespace":"default","resourceVersion":"533184","selfLink":"/apis/k8s.test.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/greetings/demo","uid":"40f3a618-74e5-4b14-9bd4-2eb47366d804"},"spec":{"message":"Hi there!"},"status":{"ready":true}}}
```

**Why is it MODIFYING the parent resource??**

And if we inspect the resource, we can see that that `status` of the subresource was definitely updated:

```
$ k get grt demo
NAME   READY
demo   true
```

**I don't know if this behaviour is expected and my understanding is faulty OR if my `PATCH` methodology is flawed.**

Hope somebody can help out. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

In addition to `PATCH` I can also confirm that `PUT` (while a more complicated operation) exhibits the exact same behaviour.

Example:

```
curl -k -s -X PUT -H "Accept: application/json, */*" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
127.0.0.1:8001/apis/k8s.test.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/greetings/demo/status \
--data '{"apiVersion":"k8s.test.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Greeting","metadata":{"name":"demo","resourceVersion":"533184"},"status":{"ready":false}}'
```

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 5):

The `status` subresource isn't actually a different object; it is just a separate API path that can only modify the top-level `status:` block in the object.  This is useful because you can [set up an RBAC policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) for your controller to allow read access to the whole object, but only allow writing the object's status.

In particular, you see this in your last command.  If you `kubectl get grt demo -o yaml`, the extended YAML syntax will include the `status:` sub-block.  The controller updating the status will cause a visible change in the `status:`, so you should reasonably expect that a watch will see this as a change.

Comment: If that's the case, then how can a k8s Operator watch a resource or list of resources and react appropriately to different events (ADDED, MODIFIED, etc.)? 

Here's an example:
1. resource is created
2. operator detects ADDED
3. operator updates /status (PATCH)
4. operator detects MODIFIED

Without any distinction between the resource and its subresource, the watch will detect the same Operator updating the custom resource's /status.

Comment: Thanks to the `generation` field of the object metadata. This field is updated when the `spec` subresource of an object is modified. A well constructed operator then should not react to any further event for which the `generation` field of the associated object is less or equal to the one of an event already processed (`observedGeneration` in the `status` subresource can help on that matter).